# problema al relacionar con el ORM eloquent de laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, orm

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en laravel 5.5 que trabaja con fichas (datos personales) y tengo la respectiva tabla también tengo una tabla comunas que esta relacionado a la tabla fichas es decir una relación uno a uno una ficha puede tener una comuna, tengo varias fichas y al momento de ir a buscar la relación con las comunas me da el error les mostrare mi código

el metodo de mi fichaController

```
public function BuscarFicha(){
      $fichas= fichas::all();
      $fichas->comuna;
        //dd($fichas);
        return view('Ficha.BuscarFicha',compact('fichas'));
    }
```

el modelo de fichas

```
 public function comuna()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(comunas::class);
    }
```

si lo realizo asi

```
$fichas->first();
$fichas->comuna();
```

no hay problema pero quiero traer todas las fichas, en que me puedo estar equivocando?

Comment: No entiendo exactamente que es lo que quieres hacer, ¿simplemente quieres mostrar todas las fichas que obtuviste con `$fichas::all()`?

Comment: @Shaz si pero tambien quiero mostrar los datos de la tabla comuna que estan en el campo comuna_id de la tabla ficha, me explico bien?

Comment: El nombre del Modelo debería iniciar en letra mayúscula y en singular  , debería ser `Comuna::class` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es mostrar todas las fichas obtenidas y sus respectivas comunas, lo primero que deberías hacer es cargar la relación al momento de obtener las fichas, para evitar un problema de N+1 :

```
$fichas  = fichas::with('comuna')->get();
```

Posteriormente, en blade, puedes utilizas @forelse para iterar por la colección y mostrar su información:

```
@forelse ($fichas as $ficha)
  <div>
     Nombre de ficha: {{ $ficha->nombre }}
     Nombre de comuna: {{ $ficha->comuna->nombre }}
  </div>
@empty
  <p>No hay fichas</p>
@endforelse
```

Utilicé como ejemplo hipotético el nombre, pero simplemente reemplazas las propiedades respectivas.

Documentación:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#loops

Comment: wow eres increible, era lo que necesitaba muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer al declarar la relación con tu módelo Fichas es

```
public function comuna()
{
    // Debe de recibir el nombre completo de la clase
    return $this->belongsTo(Comunas::className());
}
```

Eager loading lo que hace es evitar hacer una consulta cada vez que llamas a `$ficha->comuna`, que seria el select de la tabla comuna buscando po el `id_ficha`.